# Rewrite URLs in RESTful API

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to create an API in PHP, which I have never done before. I have a index.php in my root folder which contains a form. A button click activates an AJAX Request to read all entries and a form can be filled out to send data. I will also have DELETE and update.

**ajaxcall.js**

```
 // GET to retrieve
 var req;
   req=new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open("GET", 'src/api/v1/posts',true);
   req.send();

  //post with ajax
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "src/api/v1/posts",
        data: test,
        ContentType:"application/json",

        success:function(){
            alert('successfully posted');
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('Could not be posted');
        }

    });
```

I have a folder src/api/v1 in there I want the endpoint file api.php which handles the different requests. I now need all the AJAX calls to be resend to api.php which sits inside that v1 folder. I created an .htaccess which is stored in also stored in src/api/v1. I added the following:

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule src/api/v1/(.*)$ src/api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Unfortunately I get a 404 not found, it just does not seem to re-write the URL to the api.php so it is looking for /posts which does not exists. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should store the `.htaccess` on the root directory, otherwise Apache will not know that there's an `.htaccess` under `/src/api/v1`, so apache will look for the directory `src/api/v1/posts` and as is it's not found a 404 error will be returned.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule src/api/v1/(.*)$ /src/api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much Kerkouch. I am such a lemon that I did not think of that. I suppose I did not realise that because when callled up src/api/v1/ with AJAX, than it would jump into the index.php so I actually thought it is aware. But now it finally works and I do not have to call up any create.php, read.php etc directly which would have been horrible. Thank you !

Comment: I'm glad it helped!